# Postman: TypeError: User.findOne is not a function

Tags: javascript, methods

Postman: TypeError: `User.findOne` is not a function

Hi, I'm trying to run the POST request at the end of the lecture and I got this error.

I think the problem is with the `User.findOne` method.

My code as follows:

```
//users.js


const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const gravatar = require('gravatar');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// Load User Model
const User = require('../../models/User');

//@route GET api/users/test
//@description Test users route
//@access Public

router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.json({
  msg: 'Users Works'
}));

//@route GET api/users/register
//@description Register a user
//@access Public

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        email: 'Email already exists'
      });
    } else {

      const avatar = gravatar.url(req.body.email, {
        s: '200',
        r: 'pg',
        d: 'mm'
      });

      const newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        avatar,
        password: req.body.password
      });

      // encryption of password, throw and catch of error
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          newUser.password = hash;
          newUser
            .save()
            .then(user => res.json(user))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

        });
      });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Can you give us details about the file structure? Are you sure User is not located at '../models/User'? Did you export the function findOne like module.exports = {findOne : findOne}; ?

Comment: solved the  problem, had to remove the throws, line and change it with console.log and also the findOne variable. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again. I am facing the same problem and removing throws doesn't solve the problem. This code is from one of Brad Traversy Udemy course - MERN Stack Front To Back Full Stack React, Redux & Node.js. Chapter 3